# Stored Procedure doesn't show result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure (to be used in SSRS) that has parameters whose values are more than one. When I execute this stored procedure in SSMS by providing the values for that parameter, SP doesn't return any result. It should return more than 1 rows

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tst_CSENG_JulieCapitalHours]
    @StartDate DATETIME ,
    @EndDate DATETIME ,
    @ProjHomeGrp NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @ProjHier NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
    BEGIN

        SELECT  [Capital Project] ,
                [Capital Task] ,
                ResourceName ,
                ProjectName ,
                [Project Home Group] ,
                ActualWork ,
                TimeByDay ,
                ResourceStandardRate ,
                ActualWork * ResourceStandardRate AS Dollars ,
                [Project Hierarchy]
        FROM    [IR.CapOnly]
        WHERE   ( TimeByDay >= @StartDate )
                AND ( [Project Home Group] = ( @ProjHomeGrp ) )
                AND ( TimeByDay <= @EndDate )
                AND ( ActualWork > 0 )
                AND ( [Project Hierarchy] = ( @ProjHier ) )
        ORDER BY ProjectName ,
                ResourceName

    END
```

You can see that in the where clause, Project Home Group (@ProjHomeGrp) and Project Hierarchy (@ProjHier) are the parameters, whose value when supplied (more than 1) SP returns zero values.

The value that I'm passing are:

Start Date: 1/1/2011  
End Date: 12/31/2012  
@ProjHomeGrp : PHG1,PHG2,PHG3,PHG4,PHG5,PHG6,PHG7  
@ProjHier: PROH1, PROH2, PROH3

Let me know for any questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split your parameters into rows and use `where ... in` as a check.

Using a split function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314917/569436) your code could look like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tst_CSENG_JulieCapitalHours]
    @StartDate DATETIME ,
    @EndDate DATETIME ,
    @ProjHomeGrp NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @ProjHier NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ProjHomeGrpTbl TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(4))

    INSERT INTO @ProjHomeGrpTbl(Value)
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(s))
    FROM dbo.Split(',', @ProjHomeGrp);

    DECLARE @ProjHierTbl TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(5))

    INSERT INTO @ProjHierTbl(Value)
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(s))
    FROM dbo.Split(',', @ProjHier);

    SELECT  [Capital Project] ,
            [Capital Task] ,
            ResourceName ,
            ProjectName ,
            [Project Home Group] ,
            ActualWork ,
            TimeByDay ,
            ResourceStandardRate ,
            ActualWork * ResourceStandardRate AS Dollars ,
            [Project Hierarchy]
    FROM    [IR.CapOnly]
    WHERE   ( TimeByDay >= @StartDate )
            AND ( [Project Home Group] in (SELECT Value FROM @ProjHomeGrpTbl) )
            AND ( TimeByDay <= @EndDate )
            AND ( ActualWork > 0 )
            AND ( [Project Hierarchy] in (SELECT Value FROM @ProjHierTbl) )
    ORDER BY ProjectName ,
            ResourceName

END
```

Comment: I have updated your comment with my inputs.

Comment: `String or binary data would be truncated.` You need to adapt the field size of the table variables to whatever sizes you need. I choose `4`and `5` based on the data you provided in your question. It should be the same sizes as `[Project Home Group]` and `[Project Hierarchy]`.