# Stored Procedure is not returning complete result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I am using the query as mentioned in the answer accepted in the question located at [Stored Procedure doesn't show result in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/stored-procedure-doesnt-show-result-in-sql-server)

Now when I run this SP with the values provided in the parameter, the SP shows results only of specific parameter values when returning the result. Can there be any chance of values getting terminated? The parameter values are multiple and comma seperated.

Below is the SP;

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tst_JulieExportCSENGOnly]
    @ProjectHierarchy NVARCHAR(max),
    @ProjectHomeGroup NVARCHAR(max),
    @ProjName NVARCHAR(max),
    @ProjOwn NVARCHAR(max),
    @TimeByDay DATETIME,
    @TimeByDay2 DATETIME
AS 
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   BEGIN

   DECLARE @ProjectHierarchyTbl TABLE ( Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
   DECLARE @ProjectHomeGroupTbl TABLE ( Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
   DECLARE @ProjNameTbl TABLE ( Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
   DECLARE @ProjOwnTbl TABLE ( Value NVARCHAR(MAX))

    INSERT  INTO @ProjectHierarchyTbl
        ( Value )
        SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(s))
        FROM    dbo.Split(',', @ProjectHierarchy) ; 

   INSERT  INTO @ProjectHomeGroupTbl
        ( Value )
        SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(s))
        FROM    dbo.Split(',', @ProjectHomeGroup) ; 


    INSERT  INTO @ProjNameTbl
        ( Value )
        SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(s))
        FROM    dbo.Split(',', @ProjName) ; 

    INSERT  INTO @ProjOwnTbl
        ( Value )
        SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(s))
        FROM    dbo.Split(',', @ProjOwn) ;  

   SELECT
  [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Departments]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ProjectName
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ProjectOwnerName
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Hierarchy]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Home Group]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[CSENG Project Type]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TaskName
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Capital Project]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Capital Task]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ResourceName
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].ActualWork
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Resource Home Group]
  ,[IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Resource Cost Center]
  ,[ResourceStandardRate]
FROM
  [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay]
WHERE
  [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Departments] LIKE N'CSENG'
  AND ActualWork > 0
  AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Hierarchy] IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @ProjectHierarchyTbl)
  AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].[Project Home Group] IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @ProjectHomeGroupTbl)
  AND ProjectName IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @ProjNameTbl)
  AND ProjectOwnerName IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @ProjOwnTbl)
  AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay >= @TimeByDay
  AND [IR.TimesheetProjectHoursByDay].TimeByDay <= @TimeByDay2

   END
```

Thanks!

Comment: to clarify - you are passing in a list like `PHG1,PHG2,PHG3,PHG4,PHG5,PHG6,PHG7` and only getting results like `PHG1,PHG2,PHG3,PHG4,PHG5`?

Comment: I am getting lesser records then expected in the result set. It looks the values in the list are getting terminated when executing the SP.

Comment: Then I would suspect your varaible is too small to contain the whole list. Not necesarrily the one in the proc, but where ever teh list is generated from in the application. Use profiler to see what is being sent to the stored proc.

Comment: In the proc, the data type is nvarchar(max) which i guess is sufficient. The SP is called when the report is executed. Report is build using SSRS.

Comment: It would only be truncated if you used a different data type of you weren't properly passing all of the values. Please show your code where you define and populate the parameter to pass. Anything short of that can only lead to guesswork.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I have edit the question with the Stored Procedure. Would you require any kind of data here?

Comment: We need to see the application code where you call the stored procedure. Inside the stored procedure your vales aren't getting truncated unless your version of dbo.Split is different (e.g. Uses parameters or variables < max). More likely your application code is truncating the string. You could output the data length of each of the variables to try and track down where the data is getting lost.

Comment: If you use the `split` function referenced in the other answer the split is truncating your valuelist to `varchar(512)`.

Comment: Yes @MikaelEriksson, you are right. The value is getting truncated to 512. How to avoid that? I tried changing that to nvarchar(max) but it shows the error of 
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "start" of recursive query "Pieces".

Comment: Maybe easier to use a different split function that doesn't have this limitation. Though do you really have individual values > 512 characters? Is this expected or perhaps it is a delimiter problem?

Comment: See my answers here for different split function alternatives : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274514/sql-query-to-match-keywords http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182533/efficient-query-to-split-a-delimited-column-into-a-separate-table

Comment: @AaronBertrand The problem with the split OP is using is that the input comma separated string is truncated to 512.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson that's what I assumed but it wasn't 100% clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split function you use truncate the valuelist to `varchar(512)`. There are several split functions to choose from in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/314824/569436) and here is another.

```
create function dbo.Split(@sep char(1), @s varchar(max))
returns @T table(s varchar(max))
as
begin
  while len(@s) > 0
  begin
    insert into @T values(left(@s, charindex(@sep, @s+@sep)-1))
    set @s = stuff(@s, 1, charindex(@sep, @s+@sep), '')
  end
  return
end
```

Comment: This surely brings more record than the previous function did.But it doesn't bring all records :-(